# Visual Studio: disabling unused components to improve developer efficiency

Tags: visual-studio-2010, customization

Visual Studio 2010 comes with a huge set of tools, most of which aren't useful to me.  These things possibly slow visual studio down, but they certainly slow *me* down by introducing irrelevant visual clutter all over the place.

Is it possible to selectively uninstall or disable certain Visual Studio components?

Specifically, I'd want to get rid of "Test Tools", "Workflow anything" "Windows Forms anything" "Source Control anything" and on some machines "Data anything".

I can customize menus, but that takes time and effort and there's no easy way to cleanly export only those modifications (i.e., to separate other user settings from these more global modifications), and these tools appear in lots of context sensitive pops too (so that's a hassle).

Alternatively, can I repurpose this functionality to connect to mercurial+svn rather than Team System, and to use NUnit/xUnit/boost::test rather than Team System functionality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, no, at least in the manner you describe.

Sounds like a good idea for [an extension](http://wovs.com/).  If you create a new idea for this, @me here so I'll know to nip over and vote for it.

BTW, have you ever run Visual Studio 2010 in [/safemode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241278.aspx)?  I've noticed that extensions are what make VS run slow.  In safe mode, VS starts up in about three to five seconds on my core 2 quad.  Takes about 3x as long normally.